# Can't add picture into database

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to do the following things:

1. Add a new picture into database (into column named "PicProfile").
2. Copy the path/location into the textBox (named image_path_txt). In
   addition, I can add a record with the other fields except the image.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
    byte[] imageBT = null;

    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.image_path_txt.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 

     BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
     imageBT = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
     string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=amg135468lns";
     string Query = "insert into db.newuser (FName,LName,Age,Gender,Phone_No, Mobile_No,City, Street, Street_No,Email,idNewUser,PicProfile)"+ "values('" + this.Fname_txt.Text + "','" + this.Lname_txt.Text + "','"+this.Age_txt.Text+"','"+this.Gender+"','" + this.Phone_txt.Text + "','" + this.Mobile_txt.Text + "','" + this.City_txt.Text + "','" + this.Street_txt.Text + "','" + this.StreetNo_txt.Text + "','" + this.Email_txt + "','"+this.user_no_txt.Text+"',@PicP);";  

     MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
     MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query,conDataBase);
     MySqlDataReader myReader;

     try
     {
         conDataBase.Open();
         cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@PicP", imageBT));

         myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
         MessageBox.Show("Saved");
         while (myReader.Read())
         {

         }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }

}
```

Comment: what error messages do you get? also you don't need a reader for inserting. Try `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Where to start....

Comment: "Empty path name is not legal."- This is the exception.  this the line taht related to the exception:  FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.image_path_txt.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

Comment: That error suggests that you file path is not correct. can you post an example of what you have in `this.image_path_txt.Text`

Answer (score 2):

> Empty path name is not legal.

If that's the error; it's pretty self-explanatory. You're providing an empty path. Or, in other words, the `Text` of `this.image_path_txt` is *empty.*

---

Wow. So let's start with the *why you can't add it to the database.* You can't issue an `ExecuteReader` against an `INSERT` statement. So, instead of:

```
myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("Saved");
while (myReader.Read())
{

}
```

just do this:

```
cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, instead of all of this:

```
byte[] imageBT = null;

FileStream fstream = new FileStream(
    this.image_path_txt.Text,
    FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read); 

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
imageBT = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
```

just do this:

```
byte[] imageBT = File.ReadAllBytes(this.image_path_txt.Text);
```

Next, let's move on to resource management. You need to leverage the `using` statement here:

```
using (MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
using (MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query,conDataBase))
{
    // add parameters

    // execute the statement
}
```

Next, let's move on to SQL Injection attacks. Right now you're building a query that's wide open to SQL Injection because it's not fully parameterized. It should read something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (@field1, @field2, @field3)
```

and then when you add the parameters, just do this:

```
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", txtField1.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", txtField2.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field3", imageBT);
```

Comment: +1: Very thourough. In addition: Avoid hard coding connection strings

Comment: @musefan, Thanks! And yeah I think I'd suggest that as well. But let's leave it as a comment. I don't want to delve into that ... :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will do as you suggest.